# $\text{lcm}(a, b, c) = \frac{ab + bc + ca}4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Find all tuples of positive integers
> $(a, b, c)$ such that,
> $$\text{lcm}(a, b, c) = \frac{ab + bc + ca}4$$

The hint is "If $p\, | \,(b + c)$, then $p\, |\, bc$. What does this give?"

I've read the solution [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2005700p14037444).

But, I'm quite struggling on how to get $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)=bc$ and $a |bc$

Comment: What did you try so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to use the gcd properties and end up into false statements, so I looked up to the solutions in aops and now I am strugglling to prove lcm (a,b,c) = bc

Comment: We have $5\mid (2+3)$ yet $5\nmid 2\cdot3$. So I don't know what that hint is trying to say.

Comment: If a,b,c are all odd then the RHS is not integer so at least 1 of a,b,c is even...

Comment: [Japan Junior MO Finals 2020-3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2005700p14037444) $\ \ $

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Actually, at least two of $a, b, c$ must be even. If $a$ is even, then for the numerator to be divisible by $4$ (and hence even), at least one of $b$ and $c$ must also be even. Likewise, if $b$ is even, then so must at least one of $a$ and $c$, and if $c$ is even, then so must at least one of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get  $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)=bc$ and $a|bc$

Given, $$\text{lcm}(a, b, c) = \frac{ab + bc + ca}4$$

WLOG, Let us consider, $a\ge b\ge c$ i.e. $a$ is largest number among $a,b,c$.

According to LCM properties,
$$ a \mid \text{lcm}(a,b,c) {\implies a \mid 4\times\text{lcm}(a,b,c)\\
\implies a \mid (ab + bc + ca)\\
\implies a \mid bc \quad (\text{As, $ab$ and $ca$ is already divisible by $a$})\\
\implies a\mid [\text{lcm} (b,c) \times \text{gcd} (b,c)]\\(\text{product of lcm, gcd of two numbers = the product of the numbers.})\\
\implies a\mid \text{lcm} (b,c) \quad (\text{gcd$(b,c)\le c\le a$ . Hence, lcm must be divisible by $a$})\\
\implies  \text{lcm} (a,b,c)=bc}$$

Comment: I don't get the last implication. Why does $a \ge b \ge c$ and $\text{lcm} (a,bc)=bc$ together imply $\text{lcm} (a,b,c)=bc$?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang please give any counter example.

Comment: O M, I will not give a counterexample until you have attempted to show why the statement I have questioned is true. I did not say that the statement is false, only that I'm unsure whether the statement is true or not. If person A asks why person B's statement is true, then person B needs to show that it is true, not just reply back to person A and ask them to show that the statement is false. Otherwise, person A would then again ask person B to show that the statement is true, and so they would just be pointlessly arguing with each other in a circle.

Comment: $a| \text{lcm}(b,c)\cdot \text{gcd}(b,c)\implies a|\text{lcm}(b,c)$ is not a true implication. Take $(a,b,c) = (9,6,3)$ for example.